# Social Sharing with CRNA (Create React Native App)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

How can I share images and text using CRNA (create react native app) on facebook/twitter?

I went through the documentation, but I could not find anything.

Any leads here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Share` API (https://reactnative.dev/docs/share) of React Native to show the native sharing dialog of iOS/Android.

Comment: I checked this , but was facing some issues hence logged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093270/react-native-share-examples and it looks like  people misunderstood my intentions and started downvoting my question :(

Comment: On iOS you can remove sharing methods from the dialog that pops up using the `excludedActivityTypes` setting. See this example: https://snack.expo.io/@bacon/share:-excluded-activity-types.